# Схема реализации сайта с обновления данных с другого сайта

Tags: c#, python, веб-программирование, архитектура, проектирование

Думаю над созданием сайта, который парсит другой сайт сохраняет данные в базу, а затем выводит эти данные в таблицу с моими фильтрами и так далее.

Пока думаю так, написать консольную программу, которая в цикле парсит изменения на сайте и пишет их в базу.
А затем сайт с помощью аякс ловит обновления из базы и обновляет инфу на сайте. А есть какие-то другие варианты решения этой задачи?

Comment: Вполне рабочая схема, имхо. Может, консольку имеет смысл на сервис поменять, но можно и консолькой оставить, если она падать не будет.